# Non-nullable instance field must be initialized and Unhandled error LateInitializationError

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to create a database and store an API token for user login but I keep getting an error when the app builds/compiles:

> Non-nullable instance field '_database' must be initialized

I've tried adding a late modifier as suggested which then throws:

> E/flutter ( 6894): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(199)]
> Unhandled Exception: Unhandled error LateInitializationError: Field
> '_database@637109567' has not been initialized. occurred in Instance
> of 'AuthenticationBloc'.

my user_db.dart

```
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:path/path.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
import 'package:sqflite/sqflite.dart';

final userTable = 'userTable';



class DatabaseProvider {
  static final DatabaseProvider dbProvider = DatabaseProvider();
  //non nullable error on _database
  Database _database;

  Future <Database> get database async {

    print('before condition');
    if (_database != null){
      return _database;
    }
    _database = await createDatabase();
    return _database;
  }

  createDatabase() async {
    Directory documentsDirectory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    String path = join(documentsDirectory.path, "User.db");

    var database = await openDatabase(
      path,
      version: 1,
      onCreate: initDB,
      onUpgrade: onUpgrade,
    );
    return database;
  }

  void onUpgrade(
      Database database,
      int oldVersion,
      int newVersion,
      ){
    if (newVersion > oldVersion){}
  }

  void initDB(Database database, int version) async {
    await database.execute(
        "CREATE TABLE $userTable ("
            "id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, "
            "username TEXT, "
            "token TEXT "
            ")"
    );
  }
}
```

my AuthBloc.dart

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:bloc/bloc.dart';
import 'package:meta/meta.dart';
import 'package:equatable/equatable.dart';

import 'package:times/repository/user_repository.dart';
import 'package:times/model/user_model.dart';

part 'authentication_event.dart';
part 'authentication_state.dart';

class AuthenticationBloc
    extends Bloc<AuthenticationEvent, AuthenticationState> {

  AuthenticationBloc({required this.userRepository})
      : super(AuthenticationUnauthenticated())
  ;

  final UserRepository userRepository;

  @override
  Stream<AuthenticationState> mapEventToState(
    AuthenticationEvent event,
  ) async* {
    if (event is AppStarted) {

      final bool hasToken = await userRepository.hasToken();

      if (hasToken) {
        yield AuthenticationAuthenticated();
      } else {
        yield AuthenticationUnauthenticated();
      }
    }

    if (event is LoggedIn) {
      yield AuthenticationLoading();

      await userRepository.persistToken(
        user: event.user
      );
      yield AuthenticationAuthenticated();
    }

    if (event is LoggedOut) {
      yield AuthenticationLoading();

      await userRepository.deleteToken(id: 0);

      yield AuthenticationUnauthenticated();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi There. The error `LateInitializationError` must have occurred at some line. What is the line that is showing up in the debug console ?

Comment: I've added the rest of the debug - thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is being caused by this line

```
if (_database != null) {
```

You can't directly apply null check on a non-nullable variable and since it is a `late` variable and you didn't initialize it, the null check will always keep throwing the error.

One way to fix this would be to make your `_database` Nullable and instantiate it to `null`, like this

```
Database? _database = null;
```

In order to avoid using the `Nullable` type everywhere in code, you could modify your function to use the `bang` operator (`!`) like this,

```
Future <Database> get database async {
  if (_database != null){
    return _database!;
  }
  _database = await createDatabase();
  return _database!;
}
```

Comment: It works =) .. So by applying `?` to Database you have allowed it to be null and explicitly declared it to be null with `= null`. With the `bang` operator you're telling it that it can't be null (although previously declared).. is there a less complex way to do this?

Comment: `less complex` ? How is this complex :D ? This is `necessary` and I am using the `bang` operator since our ` != null` check already confirms that it won't be null.

Comment: Lol sorry complex is the wrong word. It just seems like we're telling it to be null then make sure it isn't null. Why can't we just start with it not being null in the first place or by initialising some empty object.

Comment: You can absolutely do that. But you would have to remove that `!= null` check. Have another `init` function which is going to always init the `_database` from `null` and then your `getter` can be sure that the `_database` will always be non null

Comment: You just can't both `not initialise it first` as well as `have your getter check for null`.

Comment: Thanks for your help and explanation. Really appreciate it =)

Comment: Glad to have helped :) Do consider accepting the answer if it helped you for more reach.

Comment: Sorry mate. I upvoted but forgot to accept =)